# pysqlcipher installation on ubuntu with Python 3.4 - syntaxerror

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, sqlcipher

I'm following this [tutorial](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/encrypted-sqlite-databases-with-python-and-sqlcipher/) to install pysqlcipher, but get a syntax error.

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have created a virtual environment with "virtualenv" to use Python 3.4. Despite the tutorial (of the link above), I cannot success to install sqlcipher! The installation crashes when I run this:

```
python setup.py build_sqlcipher
```

The error message is this one:

```
  File "setup.py", line 64
    print "CFLAGS", os.environ['CFLAGS']
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project only works on Python 2; it is not compatible with Python 3.

This specific error shows the project is using the Python 2 `print` statement, which was removed from the language in version 3. It was replaced by a *function* to do printing instead.

In all likelihood, fixing this one line is not going to be enough. You'll have to ask the project maintainers if they have any plans in supporting Python 3. I see the project [already has a ticket open](https://github.com/leapcode/pysqlcipher/issues/3) asking for support, it looks like the project is already working on supporting this, but it is not ready at this point in time.

Instead, install [Python 2.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python) on your Ubuntu machine and run the code with that version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have just tried to install pysqlcipher with Python 2.7.6 and now i get his error:  `#include "sqlite3.h"
                     ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`. Do you have an idea how to solve this error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KevHV: you most likely need the `sqlite` development headers; there'll be a Ubuntu `sqlite-dev` or `libsqlite-dev` package or similar.

Comment: @KevHV: install this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libsqlite3-dev to get the include headers. Generally speaking, when compiling against a project, make sure you have the `-dev` package for that project so that the compiler can find the appropriate files to include.

Comment: Thanks so so much, really thank you!! Nearly 3 weeks I cannot find out how to install this module! Thanks to your last reply I have applied those command lines `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` and then `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`. Then I have had no anymore message error. Thank you again!